# New Admin Module created showing 404 error

Tags: magento-1.9, router

I'm building an Admin module for the first time by following [this tutorial](http://inchoo.net/magento/getting-started-with-building-admin-module-in-magento/)

I have created everything & the module is showing in the backend, but when  I clicked the submenu of my module, instead of showing the controller content, what i can see is the "page not found" html page !!

**The config details :**

```
<config>
<modules>
  <Pgs_AramexSync>
    <version>1.1.0</version>
  </Pgs_AramexSync>
</modules>
<global>
  <models>
    <aramexSync>
        <class>Pgs_AramexSync_Model</class>
    </aramexSync>
  </models>
<helpers>
    <aramexHelper>
        <class>Pgs_AramexSync_Helper</class>
    </aramexHelper>
</helpers>
 <events>
      <catalog_product_save_after>
        <observers>
            <aramexSync>
                <class>aramexSync/observer</class>
                <method>productUpdate</method>
            </aramexSync>
        </observers>
    </catalog_product_save_after>
</events>
</global>
<admin>
<routers>
    <aramexHelper>
        <use>admin</use>
        <args>
            <module>Pgs_AramexSync</module>
            <frontname>aramexsync</frontname>
        </args>
    </aramexHelper>
</routers>
</admin>
<adminhtml>
<menu>
    <menu1 translate="title">
     <title>Aramex Warehouse Sync</title>
        <sort_order>90</sort_order>
            <children>
                <menuitem_1>
                    <title>Prepare Shipments</title>
                    <action>adminhtml/aramexsync/warehouse</action>
                </menuitem_1>
            </children>                
    </menu1>
</menu>
<acl>
    <resources>
        <admin>
            <children>
                <menu1 translate="title">
                    <title>Aramex Warehouse sync</title>
                    <sort_order>90</sort_order>
                    <children>
                        <menuitem_1>
                            <title>Prepare Aramex Warehouse Shipment</title>
                        </menuitem_1>
                    </children>
               </menu1>
           </children>
       </admin>
    </resources>
 </acl>
<acl>
    <resources>
        <admin>
            <children>
                <system>
                    <children>
                        <config>
                            <children>
                                <aramexSync_options>
                                    <title>Pgs Aramex Sync Settings</title>
                                </aramexSync_options>
                            </children>
                        </config>
                    </children>
                </system>
            </children>
        </admin>
    </resources>
</acl>
```

**The controller :**
*App->local->Pgs->AramexSync->controllers*

```
<?php

     class Pgs_AramexSync_WarehouseController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action{
    public function indexAction() {
        $this->loadLayout();
        $this->_addContent($this->getLayout()->createBlock('core/template'));
        echo "Hello World";
        $this->renderLayout();
    }   
}
```

I am working in Magento 1.9, I can't figure out what is wrong with the code.

Comment: Even try to refer http://www.bubblecode.net/en/2012/02/08/magento-create-your-own-admin-controller-in-a-new-tab/, http://inchoo.net/magento/how-to-create-a-custom-grid-from-scratch/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change below code of config.xml :

```
<admin>
<routers>
    <aramexHelper>
        <use>admin</use>
        <args>
            <module>Pgs_AramexSync</module>
            <frontname>aramexsync</frontname>
        </args>
    </aramexHelper>
</routers>
</admin>
```

to:

```
<admin>
    <routers>
        <adminhtml>
            <args>
                <modules>
                    <aramexHelper after="Mage_Adminhtml">Pgs_AramexSync_Adminhtml</aramexHelper>
                </modules>
            </args>
        </adminhtml>
    </routers>
</admin>
```

Add controller to

```
<?php

     class Pgs_AramexSync_Adminhtml_WarehouseController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action{
    public function indexAction() {
        $this->loadLayout();
        $this->_addContent($this->getLayout()->createBlock('core/template'));
        echo "Hello World";
        $this->renderLayout();
    }   
}
```

Change link :

```
<action>adminhtml/aramexsync/warehouse</action>
```

to:

```
<action>adminhtml/warehouse/index</action>
```

Comment: Still "The page not found " html page is showing, i had flushed the cache, logged out & loggedin again !!

Comment: thanks buddy!! its working !! adminhtml folder was lowercase(adminhtml)

Answer (score 0):

Controller file should be placed in adminhtml folder, since the URL you are redirecting from menu is using admin router path.

Second thing, **`<action>adminhtml/aramexsync/warehouse</action>`** should be **`<action>adminhtml/aramexhelper/warehouse</action>`**.

Third thing, from menu you are redirecting to **`warehouse`** action, but in controller there is no action like **`warehouse`**.

Comment: I tried this, but not working !!

Comment: Please check edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

Add bellow code in `config.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
<modules>
  <Pgs_AramexSync>
    <version>1.1.0</version>
  </Pgs_AramexSync>
</modules>
<admin>
    <routers>
        <aramexsync>
            <use>admin</use>
            <args>
                <module>Pgs_AramexSync</module>
                <frontName>aramexsync</frontName>
            </args>
        </aramexsync>
    </routers>
</admin>   
<global>
  <models>
    <aramexSync>
        <class>Pgs_AramexSync_Model</class>
    </aramexSync>
  </models>
<helpers>
    <aramexHelper>
        <class>Pgs_AramexSync_Helper</class>
    </aramexHelper>
</helpers>
 <events>
      <catalog_product_save_after>
        <observers>
            <aramexSync>
                <class>aramexSync/observer</class>
                <method>productUpdate</method>
            </aramexSync>
        </observers>
    </catalog_product_save_after>
</events>
</global>
<adminhtml>
<menu>
    <menu1 translate="title">
     <title>Aramex Warehouse Sync</title>
        <sort_order>90</sort_order>
            <children>
                <menuitem_1>
                    <title>Prepare Shipments</title>
                    <action>aramexsync/adminhtml_warehouse/</action> 
                </menuitem_1>
            </children>                
    </menu1>
</menu>
<acl>
    <resources>
        <admin>
            <children>
                <menu1 translate="title">
                    <title>Aramex Warehouse sync</title>
                    <sort_order>90</sort_order>
                    <children>
                        <menuitem_1>
                            <title>Prepare Aramex Warehouse Shipment</title>
                        </menuitem_1>
                    </children>
               </menu1>
           </children>
       </admin>
    </resources>
 </acl>
<acl>
    <resources>
        <admin>
            <children>
                <system>
                    <children>
                        <config>
                            <children>
                                <aramexSync_options>
                                    <title>Pgs Aramex Sync Settings</title>
                                </aramexSync_options>
                            </children>
                        </config>
                    </children>
                </system>
            </children>
        </admin>
    </resources>
</acl>
</adminhtml>
</config>
```

Create controller file `WarehouseController.php` at location `app\code\local\Pgs\AramexSync\controllers\Adminhtml`

and add bellow code in controller file

```
<?php
class Pgs_AramexSync_Adminhtml_WarehouseController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action
{

    public function indexAction()
    {
        $this->loadLayout();
        echo "Hello World";
        $this->renderLayout();
    }
}
```